# Wrong question titles when refreshing the achievements screen in the android app when

Tags: bug, android-app

Refreshing (by dragging down) the Achievements screen in the Stack Overflow Android app (not the old Stack Exchange app!) seems to show the wrong question titles, although the reputation numbers seem to be correct.

This morning I received three upvotes in the main site for three different answers (one on [Massively refactor - how to add final keyword to Java method argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42345926/2422776) (~4 hours ago), one on [Explanation for in loop javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27752659/2422776) (~1 hour ago) and one on [How to convert now() output into UnixTimestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46163076/2422776) (also ~1 hour ago)). I opened the app when I had just the first upvote of the day, and several hours later I refreshed the screen by dragging down. It correctly showed three +10 lines, but they all had the title of the first question upvoted for the day - "Massively refactor - how to add final keyword to Java method argument":

[image]

Navigating away from this screen to Questions and then back to Achievements showed the correct titles.

Technical details:
App version: 1.0.4
Android version: 6.0.1
Phone model: LG Power X (LG-K220Z)